# How to change font size inside option of a select box if it has number?

Tags: jquery, html, css

[image]

I need to change font size of number if an option in select box has number .

Comment: What have you tried? please show us your effort.

Comment: i'm getting the value from back end i tried using if($.isNumeric(value)){
$(option).css("font-size","2em;");


}    it doesnt work.

Comment: Because you didn't asked as the manual of SO said to do...where is your code and your best effort? How can we help if we don't even know where is this being used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yo cant individually style elements in options. This element is rendered by the OS, not HTML. It cannot be styled via CSS. There are replacement plug-ins that look like a SELECT, but are actually composed from regular HTML elements that CAN be styled.

Use instead

https://github.com/HubSpot/select

or

https://select2.org/

Answer (score 0):

Prad, you can change the font size with CSS that targets the `<select>` element, but without seeing any HTML or existing CSS, it's tough to guess what's being used. Can you please clarify your question?

```css
select {
  font-size: 18px;
}
```

```html
<select>
  <option>12:00am</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I need numeric should have a different font size pls.

Comment: Are you using some sort of time selection library? A screenshot is useless without any context of the code behind it.

Comment: yes our backed people are using util library to select some timezone i'm not using any fronted library.